# Why does my function not recognise my other function in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Why do I get the error:  `Uncaught ReferenceError: writeUserData is not defined(…)`

or the other error when i include `this.writeUserData` which is: `Cannot read property 'writeUserData' of undefined`

The function still posts the correct data to firebase so why is it complaining?
and more so what is the correct way to call a function inside another function. i thought this was the right way to do it?

```
signUserUp(){
    let name = this.state.nameValue;
    let slackName = this.state.slackNameValue;
    let email = this.state.emailValue;
    let password = this.state.passwordValue;
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(
      function(result){
        writeUserData(name, result.uid, email, slackName);
      },
      function(error){
        let errorCode = error.code;
        let errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log(errorMessage, '***');
        console.log(errorCode, 'code');
        });
    };

    writeUserData(name, useruid, email, slackName){
      firebase.database().ref('/pairs/' + useruid).set({
        name: name,
        useruid: useruid,
        email: email,
        slackName: slackName
      });
    }
```

EDIT: This code is inside a React component using ES6 syntax...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you first question: The reason is that you didn't declare `writeUserData` as a function.

Here is a way similar to Alexey Soshin's answer, but with an alternative syntax.

```js
var signUserUp = function() {
    let name = this.state.nameValue;
    let slackName = this.state.slackNameValue;
    let email = this.state.emailValue;
    let password = this.state.passwordValue;

    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(
    function(result){
        writeUserData(name, result.uid, email, slackName);
    },
    function(error){
        let errorCode = error.code;
        let errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log(errorMessage, '***');
        console.log(errorCode, 'code');
    });
};

var writeUserData = function (name, useruid, email, slackName) {
    firebase.database().ref('/pairs/' + useruid).set({
        name: name,
        useruid: useruid,
        email: email,
        slackName: slackName
    });
}
```

For your second question ("...when I include `this.writeUserData` ... `Cannot read property 'writeUserData' of undefined`"): In this case `this` is undefined.

To define `this` for your second question, you'd have to define your `writeUserData` inside `this`.

To define `writeUserData` inside `this`:

1. add it on the prototype of the parent function

   ```
   signUserUp.prototype.writeUserData = function(name, useruid, email, slackName) { ... }
   ```
2. bind the `this` of the parent function to the child function

   ```
   firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then( ... ).bind(this);
   ```
3. bind the `this` of the child function to your function

   ```
   function(result) { ... }.bind(this),
   ```

... which is awkward. So do it the first way! :)

```js
var signUserUp = function() {
  let name = this.state.nameValue;
  let slackName = this.state.slackNameValue;
  let email = this.state.emailValue;
  let password = this.state.passwordValue;

  signUserUp.prototype.writeUserData = function(name, useruid, email, slackName) {
    firebase.database().ref('/pairs/' + useruid).set({
      name: name,
      useruid: useruid,
      email: email,
      slackName: slackName
    });
  }

  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(
    function(result) {
      this.writeUserData(name, result.uid, email, slackName);
    }.bind(this),
    function(error) {
      let errorCode = error.code;
      let errorMessage = error.message;
      console.log(errorMessage, '***');
      console.log(errorCode, 'code');
    }).bind(this);
};
```

Comment: I declared it inside a React component and that is the ES6 way to declare a function right?

Comment: Hmm... it does look like you're thinking of ES6 classes (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes). I need to read a bit more...

Comment: To my knowledge ES6 classes do not require the function keyword when defining them

Comment: @theworm you're right... but you need the `class` keyword, I think.

Comment: I have this line at the top `class PairSwitching extends React.Component{`

Comment: I have also noticed if i do this at the top of the function `let that = this;` and then call `that.` it doesn't give me an error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129045/discussion-between-martin-jakubik-and-the-worm).

Answer (score 2):

Your just need to declare it as a function:

```
function writeUserData(name, useruid, email, slackName){...};
```

You think that it succeeds only because `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` creates your user, and only after that calls the success handler.

But this is actually never executed in your case:

```
firebase.database().ref('/pairs/' + useruid).set
```

Comment: But I declared it inside a React component using ES6 syntax which is the correct way right?